# How to get freeBoundary to respect initial triangulation vertex order. (2017a+)

Tags: matlab, computational-geometry, triangulation, surface, delaunay

This might be an x, y problem, so here is the situation I'm in.   I'm creating a sphere, generating the x, y, z points using the method defined [here](http://blog.marmakoide.org/?p=1).  But for my project, I need to be able to generate hemispheres and limit the azimuth and elevation and still have uniform point generation defined by `N` (total number of points to generate over a given spherical surface area).   I've found out how to do this, but I also needed the connectivity (roughly what were the "neighbors" of each x y z, or az, el, r=1 position).

Matlab provides something called [`delaunayTriangulation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/delaunaytriangulation.html) which won't give me the actual surface connections, but the tetrahedron connections. I found a method of getting the surface from the triangulation object returned by the `delaunayTriangulation` function, called [`freeBoundary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triangulation.freeboundary.html) which returns two things in the form `[FBtri, FBpoints]`.  `FBtri` is a n x 3 matrix of integers where each row contains a set of three integers that correspond to the rows inside the `FBpoints` (thus creating a triangle). `FBpoints` is a n x 3 matrix, where each row corresponds to the x,y,and z coordinates of a point on the surface.

The issue with `freeBoundary` is that I don't just wan't a triangle for just *any* point on the semisphere surface, only those within my azimuth elevation range.  For example, if I limit the elevation on the top of the sphere to not be above `pi/4`, then there should be a big hole on the top of the sphere. Here are some visual examples of what I did.

---

## Sphere with Bad points

[image]

## Sphere with removed points

[image]

To "solve" this issue I have a series of convoluted steps to generate "bad points" which are appending to the points used in generating the initial delaunay triangulation, and then search for in the connectivity list in the output of `freeBoundary` to remove them.  This ***could*** be done via simply removing all connections that exist after a certain index (as I append the "bad points" after the ones I actually need to use), however to my horror `freeBoundary` does not actually keep the order of points the same as the input coming from triangulation objects (and likes to scramble it, but only for the bad points I've added) so I can't easily remove invalid connections, and the indices in the connections do not actually correspond 1:1 to my original true set of points.  Here is an example of the ordering issue

---

## the actual order

[image]

## the ruined order

[image]

If I cannot force `freeBoundary` to be nice, then I'm going to have to programmically reorder the points myself, which I don't see being a fast operation in time complexity (though I may be wrong).  I believe in order to manually do this, I would have to find the new updated positions, and manually update them for each connection in the connectivity list, which is `(O(triangleCount)*changedIdxCount)` which doesn't look good for me, I'm generating thousands of points.

Here is an example of what I'm doing so far:

```
goodPoints = generateSphere(...);
badPoints = generateBadSpherePoints(...);
points = vertcat(goodPoints, badPoints);
triObj = delaunayTriangulation(points(:,1), points(:,2), points(:,3));
[FBtri, FBpoints] = freeBoundary(triObj);
...
%remove the bad points and get only good connections!
```

Comment: It's not totally clear what you want to end up with as a result. Do you want just the triangular faces in your second plot? If so, can't you just exclude all faces in `FBtri` which reference any of the vertex points you want to exclude?

Comment: @gnovice `FBtri` is actually a n x 3 matrix of point indices which refer to the row positions found in `FBpoints`, because `FBpoints` doesn't match up with the initial set of points i passed in, I can't actually use that matrix directly, and I have to update every row reference to account for the change in point position.   I need the actual indices later as well (its used in the "neighbor" part I discussed in the beginning of the post), so I can't just convert `FBtri` to just sets of points either.

Comment: So, you need the point indices in `FBtri` to reference the `points` you use to make the triangulation instead of the points in `FBpoints`?

Comment: @gnovice yes, also I'm going to try to add a thing at the end of my post that makes that more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the facets in `FBtri` to reference the points you use to make the initial triangulation instead of the vertices in `FBpoints`, all you have to do is omit capturing `FBpoints` as a second output:

```
FBtri = freeBoundary(triObj);
```

As per the [`freeBoundary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triangulation.freeboundary.html) documentation:

> The vertex IDs in `FBtri` reference a specific matrix, depending on the syntax you choose:
>
> - If you call `freeBoundary` with one output argument, then the elements of `FBtri` are row numbers of `TR.Points`.
> - If you call `freeBoundary` with two output arguments, then the elements of `FBtri` are row numbers of `FBpoints`.

Comment: Huh, I understand why one would have [FBtri, FBpoints] to make it easier to just get the points out, but what is the points of FBpoints being different, and what mechanisim causes it to be?  Any way, you solved my issue, thanks!  I'll mark this as answer in a day.

Comment: @snb: In cases where there are internal points in the 3D triangulation, they won't be referenced by any of the boundary facets, so `FBpoints` will be a subset of `TR.Points` (not an issue in this case). It's also likely that the algorithm for finding the boundary facets collects them in some unordered way, and it's more efficient to just return the unordered points than to maintain the original order/indices.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think about that.